# Finding MySQL fields ending in spaces

Tags: mysql

After a database import, there's some rows with dirty fields that end in (sometimes multiple) spaces saved in the database, and in the interest of finding them amidst the many thousands of other rows, I'm trying to do a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `dirtyfield` REGEXP ' $'
```

But that returns zero rows. I tried a few other variations with other results:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `dirtyfield` REGEXP '[[:space:]]$' -- Zero Rows
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `dirtyfield` REGEXP '[[.space.]]$' -- Zero Rows
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `dirtyfield` REGEXP '[[.space.]]' -- Those with a space anywhere in the value
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `dirtyfield` REGEXP '[[.space.]]{2}' -- Those with two spaces in a row
```

Finding all with a single space doesn't help much, since some clean rows have single spaces between words in that field. That last one catches 90% of the dirty rows, but misses those that have just a single space at the end. Is there something wrong with how I'm using the `$` symbol to indicate the end of a field?

The MySQL `RIGHT()` and `SUBSTRING()` functions seem to strip off whitespace when calculating the end of the field:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE RIGHT(`dirtyfield`)=" " -- Only returns one row that has " " for that field
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE SUBSTR(`dirtyfield`,-1)=" " -- Only returns one row that has " " for that field
```

One other try using a comparison didn't work either:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE TRIM(`dirtyfield`)!=`dirtyfield` -- zero rows returned
```

The "dirtyfield" field is a `VARCHAR(128)`, if that matters.

**EDIT:** I'm an idiot; the fields don't end in spaces, the fields end in multiple spaces followed by a comma (imported from a bad CSV file).

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE RIGHT(`dirtyfield`,1)=','
```

That query found them. I was looking at the output of the tables in a comma-separated view and didn't notice the commas were doubled-up.

Comment: can you post some line from the dump in where you are sure there are spaces?

Answer (score 7):

I think this may be correct:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `dirtyfield` REGEXP '[[.space.]]+$'
```

It matches field ending ($) with 1 or more (+) spaces ([[.space.]])
Anyway if you want to do the same thing with LIKE statement is easier with:

```
... LIKE '% '
```

as in answer below.

Comment: I tested in a local table and it works.. what if you try to SELECT replace(dirtyfield,' ','--SPACE--') ? Does any extracted row contains --SPACE--?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the spaces aren't actually spaces, but perhaps whitespace or other unprintable characters. Because the suggestions in the above answer **should** work. Perhaps try: `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE dirtyfield REGEXP '\s+$'` (I removed the backticks to format). That would return fields ending in any whitespace (such as tab, newline, etc.).

Comment: so try with regex this way:  ... REGEXP '[^0-9a-zA-Z]$'  this will match any non alphanumeric char before end.

Answer (score 7):

Had a similar problem. The compare you made with trim():

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE TRIM(`dirtyfield`)!=`dirtyfield`
```

doesnt work, but:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable where char_length(dirtyfield) > char_length(trim(dirtyfield))
```

gets the work done and shows you the rows that have spaces both at the start and/or end of the content. The character count works. Quite honestly i don't know why trim() doesn't compare directly on the first query.

Hope this helps. Like your field, this solution is admittedly a bit dirty.

Answer (score 4):

I have not tried this but I think this might work to find entries that ends with a blank space

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `dirtyfield` LIKE "% "
```

Comment: Nope, zero rows :(  If I do `LIKE "foobar%"` I get rows that have "foobar" and "foobar      ", as opposed to `LIKE "foobar"` which only returns the 'clean' "foobar" rows. But it doesn't seem to work in reverse to pick up that space.

Comment: No, the suggested query should work. Are you positive your values are really what you think they are?

Comment: Never mind, I see the question was updated to confirm the values were different than expected.

Answer (score 2):

Hey i was doing something similar and got in this page, Check below query, this might help..

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `dirtyfield` LIKE "% %"
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered that you actually get rows with spaces in it, but the web browser doesn't render them for you?

The value " two (2 or more spaces) words " looks like "two words" in your browser.

Try a:

```
WHERE dirtyfield REGEXP '(^[[:space:]]|[[:space:]]{2,}|[[:space:]]$)'
```

This should fetch all of those rows. Just consider that you might get the right rows, but it doesn't look that way due to browser.